# render datatables columns fetched via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatables

I'm using datatables via ajax and display the table like this

```
var table = $('#data').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "initTable.php",
        "columns": [
            { "data": "orderid" },
            { "data": "first_name"},
            { "data": "last_name"},
            { "data": "unix" },
            { "data": "final_total" }
        ]
    } );
```

I've tried

```
{ "data": "first_name" + "data": "last_name"},
```

But I get an error and table is not displayed. So how can I change the render to display first name next to last_name in the same cell not in the next cell

[UPDATE]

Tried

```
"ajax": "initTable.php",
"columns": [
            { "data": "orderid" },
            { "data": "first_name"},
            {"data": "last_name"},
            { "data": "unix" },
            { "data": "final_total" }
        ],
        "columnDefs": [
            {
                "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                    return data + row[2];
                },
                "targets": 1
            },
            { "visible": false,  "targets": [ 2 ] }
        ]
```

(Note: I have to define column rows because I get many columns (about 20) and want to display just 4 or 5)
But I get the first name followed by 'undefined' something like "Andy undefined"

Comment: Take a look to [column rendering](https://www.datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html)

Comment: updated please review. I get the last name 'defined'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the code below:

```
{
    "render": function ( data, type, row ){
        return row["first_name"] + " " + row["last_name"];
    },
    "targets": 1
},
```

Also there is no need to include `last_name` column if you're hiding it.

Comment: Great thanks a lot. And used:  { "visible": false,  "targets": [ 2 ] } to hide the last name field.

Comment: @PHPUser, as I said you don't have to include `last_name` field in the table and can remove `{"data": "last_name"}` and ` { "visible": false, "targets": [ 2 ] }` as long as `last_name` is available in the Ajax response.